# I get an error access denied when I execute "UiRobot.exe execute --file abc.xaml" on Azure Pipeline or Release with CMD task

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, uipath-robot

Agent host only has C drive.
I tried run `C:\Users\uania\AppData\Local\UiPath\app-21.4.4\UiRoobot.exe execute --file C:\agent\_work\1\s\src\abc.xaml` on agent host and worked well,but run this at Release,I get an error access denied. I removed agent config and reconfig with another authorized account,it still not work.

describe exception:  `UiPath.Service.UserHost 21.4.4.0 System.Threading.Tasks.Task RefreshStatus(UiPath.Service.Api.RefreshStatusParameters) # System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (access denied.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): access denied. at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.OpenProcess(Int32 processId, Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited) at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessHandle(Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited) at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetOrOpenProcessHandle() at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureWatchingForExit() at System.Diagnostics.Process.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value) at UiPath.Service.UserHost.AttendedServiceProxy.RegisterClientProcess(Int32 clientPid) at UiPath.Service.UserHost.AgentOperations.RefreshStatus(RefreshStatusParameters parameters) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---`

What else can I try?

Comment: Do you have a solution to this issue? I'm facing a very similar issue the one of my bat file goes into System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): access denied. when run from Azure-Release Pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

did you put quotation by running this file ?

This is how I call the batch file
from my device

```
start "" "C:\Users\ecaballes\AppData\Local\UiPath\app-20.10.2-beta0004\Uirobot.exe" -file "C:\Users\ecaballes\Desktop\BR EXTRACTION\main.xaml"
```

Comment: Thanks,This works well with commands or bat,but an exception is obtained by executing Azure-Pipeline or Azure-Release.The proxy account logs in to the Administrator group using a non-administrator account,the exception for uipath should be no login.I will change the agent account to Administrator and it will work normally

Comment: With the same account, it is possible to log in and run CMD, but there will be problems with the agent